# Локальная сеть Ubuntu и Windows 7, нет соединения

Tags: сеть, windows, windows-7, lan, ubuntu

Хочу управлять одной клавой и мышью двумя компами, юзаю synergy , но есть проблема, комп с Windoй7(десктоп) не видит соединения если соединить на прямую по LAN с компом на Ubuntu, самое удивительное, подключаю другой комп(ноут) с Win7 к Ubuntu все прекрасно соединяется, соответственно проблема в Win7(Десктоп), не пойму что мешает, если соединить ноут с Win7 и десктоп с Win7, то сеть определяется, гуглить задолбался, ничего не нашел.Разница в десктопе и ноуте, на десктопе стоит VirtualBox ,может из-за него? Других причин не вижу. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Стоит покопать в сторону файрволла. Synergy, ЕМНИП, использует порт 24800. Чисто теоретически, VBox тоже может влиять, ибо добавляет свой протокол в стек, но блокировать ничего не должен!

Comment: Файерволл и Synergy не причем, при втыкании сетевого кабеля в компьютер с Ubuntu и Windows7(десктоп) не реагирует никак, пишет, что сетевой кабель не подключен, а при подключении Ubuntu к другой Windows7 на ноутбуке соединяется, при соединении Windows7(десктоп) и Windows7(ноутбук) сеть идеализируется (как и описано в вопросе). Нет подключения к сети. Порты свободны, запускал Synergy на Windows7(ноутбук) и Windows7(десктоп) работает и использовал то-же сетевой кабель, он тоже в порядке.

Comment: Ну, с этого и надо было начинать! Для соединения "комп"-"комп" нужен кроссовый кабель!!! А у ноута сетевуха, судя по всему, более продвинутая, и сама разбирается где там приём-передача! Поэтому на ноуте и прямой кабель может работать. (У меня на Асусовском нетбуке точно работал!)

Comment: >>Ну, с этого и надо было начинать!    C этого и начал, вопрос нужно читать)Сегодня пробовал с подключением внешних сетевых карт с обоих сторон, тот-же результат, нет реакции.

Comment: Ну я же не про карты сетевые писал, а про кабель! Возможно, одна из жил плохо или неправильно обжата. Если есть кабель-тестер - попробуйте им проверить!

Comment: Психанул и подключил Wi-Fi карту. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Может все-таки лучше использовать KVM-свитч?
Сейчас подобные вещщи стоят копейки (на два компа с передачей звука с каждого из них)... У самого такой стоит на работе.